# Slow loading of an image as a content of CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have i custom `UIView` and i'm setting an image to the contents of a layer.
in the first time the `UIViewController` loads it takes 2-3 seconds for the image to appear.

Why is this happening? and how can i fix it.

**CODE:**

```
var buttonImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "circleArrow")!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setupView()
}

func setupView(){
    layer.contents = buttonImage.CGImage
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it is a wrong place to do this.  You can try doing this in viewDidLoad instead?

Comment: Good point, the layout event cycle is not  a good place to cause drawing.

Comment: there isn't ViewDidLoad in a UIView subclass

Comment: There are awakeFromNib or initWithCoder:

Answer (score 0):

When you set the contents, try calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your layer right away. If this doesn't work, try the same for your view.